# Lock for creation a new folder

Tags: java, io

I have the following situation: multiple threads may try to create the same folder at the same time e.g.

```
Thread 1                                    Thread 2
1 new File("\newfolder\").mkdir()           1 new File("\newfolder\").mkdir()
2                                           2   

...
```

I tried to test this situation multiple times (create the same folder using multiple thedas) and each time was successful e.g, I didn't get any problems. 
However I'm concerned about this approach - should I synchronize this code or not e.g.should I use something like

```
  try {
            folderCreationLock.lock();
            File directory = new File(directoryPath);
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdir();
            }
        } finally {
            folderCreationLock.unlock();
        }
   }
```

or am I safe with just

```
   directory.mkdir();
```

Thanks, cheers!

Comment: @AndyTurner what if two threads are trying to create the same folder at the same time? Could it result in some kind of error?

Comment: the OS should take care of this

Comment: Why do you use `File`? This is 2015, use java.nio.file

Comment: Like Wero said, the OS should take care of this particilar case. Otherwise, just use synchronized methods.

Answer (score 0):

As `fge` already mention use the NIO 2 API for it.

```
Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("\\new\\folder"));
```

This will create the directory `\\new\\folder` if directory `\\new` not exist.
 If the directory `\\new` already exists then only it's subfolder `\\folder` will be created.
 If the whole directory structure already exists nothing will be created and (maybe most important) no exception is thrown.